# Collection : Undefined k,v in Map

Tags: java, eclipse, dictionary, hashmap, java-8

i am learning about collection from this [site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html#javacollections_lambdas)

Where the guy gave the example

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// keys are Strings
// objects are also Strings
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
fillData(map);

// write to command line
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", k, v));

// add and remove from the map
map.put("iPhone", "Created by Apple");
map.remove("Android");

// write again to command line
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", k, v));

}

private static void fillData(Map<String, String> map) {
map.put("Android", "Mobile");
map.put("Eclipse IDE", "Java");
map.put("Eclipse RCP", "Java");
map.put("Git", "Version control system");

}

}
```

although in above program i can understand that k and v variable are undefined or not present locally.

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", k, v));
```

and facing the issue with same line.

Please help me learning the collections.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error?

Comment: Here's a [tutorial on Lambdas in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

Comment: @bot yes !!, FYI i have java 8 in class path

Comment: @AlexShesterov thanks :) , but can you tell me the issue with this code :)

Comment: There is no issue with this code. The only issue is with your installation system. Check that you are indeed compiling this with java 8.

Comment: Added one snapshot, containing java library 1.8

Comment: What IDE are you using (looks like it is probably Eclipse)? What release of the IDE? For Eclipse you need to be using 4.4 (Luna) to get Java 8 support.

Comment: You may have an older version of Eclipse.

Comment: don't know , i am using kepler ; is that good enough ?

Comment: @greg-449 just checked your comment , so i need to replace kepler with luna

Answer (score 3):

Correct the project properties *Java Compiler*:

**Doesn't work:**

[image]

**Works:**

[image]

Comment: +1 vote for you . Although problem is i am using kepler. But might be good for someone to configure who will face same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine on my system. Can you check are you using JDK8? Lamdas support introduced in JAVA 8. You can test java version by using `java --version`.

Comment: Added one snapshot, containing java library 1.8

Comment: To be sure, you should check the version of javac (`javac -version`), not java. Additionally, the syntax to get the version is with a single dash.

Comment: @bmesuere Added one more snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Answer of this question

You need to be using 4.4 (Luna) to get Java 8 support.

Might be useful for someone who checked it later.

Thanks @greg-449